# Typing root reducer

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

Im creating boilerplate with redux + typescript and Im faicing problem Im not sure how to solve properly.

I have code like this

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const reducer = (state: any, action: AnyAction) {
  //fill it with logic later
  return state;
}

const store = configureStore({ devTools: true, preloadedState : {counter : 12}, reducer });
```

So far it works fine. But I don't want to have 'any' as type of state. So lets state my type of state will be

`type State = { counter : number }`

so the code is now :

```
import { AnyAction, configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

type State = { counter : number } 
const reducer = (state: State, action: AnyAction) {
  //fill it with logic later
  return state;
}

const store = configureStore({ devTools: true, preloadedState : {counter : 12}, reducer});
```

I got error like this

```
Type '(state: {    counter: number;}, action: AnyAction) => { counter: number; }' is not assignable to type 'Reducer<{ counter: number; }, AnyAction> | ReducersMapObject<{ counter: number; }, AnyAction>'.
  Type '(state: {    counter: number;}, action: AnyAction) => { counter: number; }' is not assignable to type 'Reducer<{ counter: number; }, AnyAction>'.
      Types of parameters 'state' and 'state' are incompatible.
      Type '{ counter: number; } | undefined' is not assignable to type '{ counter: number; }'.
        Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '{ counter: number; }'.ts(2322)
configureStore.d.ts(21, 5): The expected type comes from property 'reducer' which is declared here on type 'ConfigureStoreOptions<{ counter: number; }, AnyAction, [ThunkMiddleware<{ counter: number; }, AnyAction, undefined>], [StoreEnhancer<{}, {}>]>'
```

I wonder what is proper approach to this.

Answer (score 0):

You see, the first parameter of a reducer is not `State`, it is (implicitly) `State | undefined` as can be seen [here (see lines ##6-7, wait for the hint to appear on #7)](https://tsplay.dev/N9bvqm), and this cannot (and should not) be changed:

[image]

Thus, your reducer takes the `state` argument (which is `State | undefined`, remember) and returns it immediately, without checking if it is really an object. But `configureStore()` expects the reducer to return an object, it cannot work with `undefined`, - hence the error.

The solution would be to return an object if `state` is `undefined`. The convention is that if `state` is `undefined`, then it is the first call of the reducer, so returning an initial state would make sense:

```
import { AnyAction, configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

type State = { counter : number }

const initial: State = { counter: 0 };

const reducer = (state: State = initial, action: AnyAction) => { // notice default value of `state`
  //fill it with logic later
  return state;
}

const store = configureStore({
  devTools: true,
  preloadedState: { counter: 12 },
  reducer,
});
```

*[Try it](https://tsplay.dev/NrDpVW)*.